Issue with RAM Usage in Parallelized forEach Loops in R on Linux
I'm currently working on a project in RStudio on Linux where I am attempting to parallelize a for loop that iterates through multiple parameter combinations for a custom function. To achieve this, I am using the foreach and doParallel packages. However, I'm encountering a significant issue with memory management during the execution of these loops.
When I run my foreach loops, the memory usage continuously increases as the loop progresses. It appears that the memory utilized is not being released back to the system, even after it is no longer needed.
Even when I stop the running process totally (by pressing the stop button in the console), the used memory won't get released.
I have already tried:

using rm(...) and gc() within the foreach loop to remove Variables that are no longer needed, this doesn't change anything
using gc() after stopping the process, this also doesn't free the used RAM
clearing all objects, including the hidden ones, almost no change in RAM usage (except for the size of the obvious Objects I deleted with that)

The only thing that immediatly frees the Ram is either stopping the cluster or restarting the R session.
I also looked at the Task manager and it seems like there is something like a R session open for every parallel process (I parallelized on 11 Cores) and by using gc() and rm() I can only effect the Main R session (marked in blue on the picture)
(https://i.sstatic.net/gwwFem7I.png)
Has anyone else faced a similar issue or can provide any insights on how to manage memory usage in parallelized foreach loops in R? Or are there maybe any other less RAM consuming ways to parallelize my code?
Here is my Code:
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(11, outfile = "", type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
total_tasks = length(15:35) * length(1:20)
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total_tasks, style = 3)
progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
opts <- list (progress = progress)
start_time <- Sys.time()
set.seed(123)
error_count <- 0
export_list <- c("train_RGLM_pois", "predict_RGLM", "gini", "dat_neu_Freq", "bootstrap_df", "subsample_df", "random_feature_select2", "stepAIC", "cramersv", "error_count")
x <-
  foreach(i=15:30, .combine='cbind', .export = export_list, .options.snow = opts) %:%
  foreach(j=1:15, .combine='c', .export = export_list) %dopar% {
    if ((j+1) <= i){
      a <- 1:80000
      b <- 200001:280000
      c <- 400001:480000
      d <- 600001:680000
      model_list <- train_RGLM_pois(random_feature_select(dat_neu_Freq[c(a, b, c),], "Anzahl_VK", "JE",i), "Anzahl_VK", "JE", 20, i, j, 1)
      prediction <- predict_RGLM(model_list, dat_neu_Freq[d,])
      gini1 <- gini(data_real = dat_neu_Freq$Anzahl_VK[d], data_pred = prediction)
      
      model_list <- train_RGLM_pois(random_feature_select(dat_neu_Freq[c(a, b, d),], "Anzahl_VK", "JE",i), "Anzahl_VK", "JE", 20, i, j, 2)
      prediction <- predict_RGLM(model_list, dat_neu_Freq[c,])
      gini2 <- gini(data_real = dat_neu_Freq$Anzahl_VK[c], data_pred = prediction)
      
      model_list <- train_RGLM_pois(random_feature_select(dat_neu_Freq[c(a, c, d),], "Anzahl_VK", "JE",i), "Anzahl_VK", "JE", 20, i, j, 3)
      prediction <- predict_RGLM(model_list, dat_neu_Freq[b,])
      gini3 <- gini(data_real = dat_neu_Freq$Anzahl_VK[b], data_pred = prediction)
      
      model_list <- train_RGLM_pois(random_feature_select(dat_neu_Freq[c(b, c, d),], "Anzahl_VK", "JE",i), "Anzahl_VK", "JE", 20, i, j, 4)
      prediction <- predict_RGLM(model_list, dat_neu_Freq[a,])
      gini4 <- gini(data_real = dat_neu_Freq$Anzahl_VK[a], data_pred = prediction)
      
      #result <- paste(as.character(MSE1 + MSE2 + MSE3 + MSE4), ",", as.character(gini1 + gini2 + gini3 + gini4), ",", as.character(dev1 + dev2 + dev3 + dev4))
      result <- (gini1 + gini2 + gini3 + gini4)/4
    } else {
      result <- 0
    }
    result
  }
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time-start_time
close(pb)
stopCluster(cl)
x # Anz_selected_features nach rechts, Anz_included_features nach unten
print(paste("Es gab", error_count, "Fehler"))


and the called functions:
library(MASS)
library(confintr)

train_RGLM_pois <- function(data, zielvariable_as_string, offsetvariable_as_string, count_glms, count_features_selected, max_features_included, CV_cycle = 0){
  model_liste <- list()
  alleGini <- c()
  i <- 0
  while (i < count_glms){
    tryCatch({
      ind <- sample(1:nrow(data), round(nrow(data)*0.7), replace = FALSE)
      BS <- data[ind,]                                                              #Bootstrap Stichprobe
      OOB <- data[-ind,]                                                            #Out Of Bag Stichprobe fÃ¼r Testen des Modells
      model_leer <- glm(as.formula(paste("BS[[zielvariable_as_string]] ~ 1 + offset(log(", offsetvariable_as_string, "))", sep = "" )) , data = BS, family = poisson(link = "log"), control = glm.control(maxit = 100))    #poisson fÃ¼r Frequency. FÃ¼r Severity wÃ¤rs dann Gamma(link = "inverse")
      model_voll <- glm(as.formula(paste(zielvariable_as_string, " ~ ", paste(names(BS[, -which(names(BS) %in% c(zielvariable_as_string, offsetvariable_as_string))]), collapse = " + "), " + offset(log(", offsetvariable_as_string, "))", sep = "")), data = BS, family = poisson(link = "log"), control = glm.control(maxit = 100))
      n = nrow(BS)
      print(paste("iteration", i + 1, "on CV Cycle", CV_cycle, "with", count_features_selected, "selec and", max_features_included, "included"))
      capture.output({BIC_output <- stepAIC(model_leer, direction = "forward", k = log(n), scope = list(lower = model_leer, upper = model_voll))}, file = "/dev/null")
      #Der String fÃ¼r die finale Formel des StepBIC 
      varStrings <- strsplit(as.character(BIC_output$call)[2], " \\+ ")[[1]]
      #Finale Formel des StepBic evtl kÃ¼rzen
      finale_formel <- paste(paste(varStrings[1:min(max_features_included, length(varStrings))], collapse = " + "), " + offset(log(", offsetvariable_as_string, "))", sep = "")
      model_final <- glm(as.formula(finale_formel), data = BS, family = poisson(link = "log"))
      #modelpredictions auf der OOB Stichprobe
      pred <- predict.glm(model_final, newdata = OOB, type = "response")
      OOB$pred <- pred
      gini <- gini(OOB[[zielvariable_as_string]], OOB$pred)
      rm(BS, OOB)
      capture.output({gc()}, file = "/dev/null")
      alleGini[i + 1] <- gini
      model_liste[[paste("model", i + 1, sep = "_")]] <- model_final
      i = i + 1
    }, error = function(e){
      assign("error_count", error_count + 1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
      print(paste("Error", e))
    })
  }
  model_liste[[count_glms + 1]] <- alleGini
  return(model_liste)
}


random_feature_select <- function(data, zielvariable, offset = "", size){
  zielvariable_index <- which(names(data) == zielvariable)
  offset_index <- which(names(data) == offset)
  ind <- sample(setdiff(1:ncol(data), c(zielvariable_index, offset_index)), size, replace = FALSE)
  return(data[,c(zielvariable_index, offset_index, ind)])
}


gini <- function(data_real, data_pred){
  data <- cbind(data_real, data_pred)
  sorted_data <- data[order(data[, 2]), ]
  n <- nrow(sorted_data)
  erg <- (2 * sum(seq_along(sorted_data[, 1]) * sorted_data[, 1])) / (n * sum(sorted_data[, 1])) - ((n + 1) / n)
  return(erg)
}

Thanks alot in advance!
Best regards
Finn
